# How to import netCDF4 file with xarray when index names have multiple dimensions?

Tags: python, python-xarray, netcdf4

When I try to import netCDF4 files using xarray I get the following error:

**MissingDimensionsError: 'name' has more than 1-dimension and the same name as one of its dimensions ('time', 'name'). xarray disallows such variables because they conflict with the coordinates used to label dimensions.**

However, I can successfully import these data using the netCDF4 python library, and get the data I need from it. The problem is that this method is very slow, so I was looking for something faster and wanted to try xarray. [Here is an example file,](https://github.com/utahTAS/Ceilometer_Data_MLH_Processing/blob/master/L3_DEFAULT_06610_201803160000_1_360_1_3120_10_30_4000_3_0_1_500_1000_4000_60.nc) and the code that is giving me the bug in question.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
#import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np         
#import seaborn as sns
from tkinter import Tk

from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
import os
import xarray as xr

#use this function to get a directory name where the files are
def get_dat():
    root = Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    root.focus_force()
    root.attributes("-topmost", True)      #makes the dialog appear on top
    filename = askdirectory()      # Open single file
    root.destroy()
    root.quit()
    return filename

directory=get_dat()

#loop through files in directory and read the netCDF4 files
for filename in os.listdir(directory):     #loop through files in user's dir
    if filename.endswith(".nc"):     #all my files are .nc not .nc4
        runstart=pd.datetime.now()
        #I get the error right here
        rootgrp3 = xr.open_dataset(directory+'/'+filename)
        #more stuff happens here with the data, but this stuff works
```

Comment: I think this is unlikely to work in xarray. As the error you're getting indicates, you have a dimension that shares a name with a 2d coordinate. While netCDF supports this, xarray does not. The easiest fix is probably to rename the dimension (or coordinate) in your netcdf file before opening with xarray.

Comment: I was worried that was the case. That was what I read, but I hoped there was a work-around. Only problem is I have 383 of these files, and I don't know of a way to quickly rename them. The comp time gets expensive when you have the 20 second read over the 383 files (about 3 hours).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is still currently valid. The problem arise when a coordinate has multiple dimensions and as the same name of one of those dimensions.

As an example, output files `result.nc` issued by  the [GOTM model](https://gotm.net/portfolio/) have this problem for coordinates `z` and `zi` :

```
dimensions:
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (4018 currently)
    lon = 1 ;
    lat = 1 ;
    z = 218 ;
    zi = 219 ;
variables:
    ... 
    float z(time, z, lat, lon) ;
    float zi(time, zi, lat, lon) ;
```

It has been proposed [here](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/2233) to implement a 'rename_var' kwarg to xr.open_dataset() as a work-around, but it hasn't been implement yet, to my knowledge.

The **quick workaround** I use is to call nco-ncrename from python, where needed.

In my case :

```
 os.system('ncrename -v z,z_coord -v zi,zi_coord result.nc resultxr.nc')
```

This allows

```
 r2 = xr.open_dataset(testdir+'resultxr.nc')
```

while

```
 r = xr.open_dataset(testdir+'result.nc')
```

was failing.

Answer (score 1):

When the variables in question are not too large, a small python-only solution
is possible:

```
import xarray as xr
import netCDF4
def xr_open_with_rename(fn,renames):
    ds=xr.open_dataset(fn,drop_variables=renames.keys())    
    ds_nc = netCDF4.Dataset(fn)
    for v in renames:
        nc_var=ds_nc[v]
        ds[renames[v]]=nc_var.dimensions,nc_var[...]
    ds_nc.close()
    ds=ds.set_coords(renames.values())    
    return ds

# e.g. open GOTM output
ds=xr_open_with_rename(nc_fn,dict(z="z_coord",zi="zi_coord"))
```

This has been useful for me when there are issues with installing nco.

Answer (score 0):

In ipython, this is a very easy workaround:

```
!ncrename -v name,name_matrix filename.nc #renaming variable name to prevent dimension/variable name conflict in xarray, requires nco in linux
```